# MouseEvent.movementX and Y is different among Firefox, Chrome, and Edge

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, cross-browser, mouseevent, dpi

I'm trying to implement a simple dragging for my frontend project. Below is the minimal working example. In essence, I set `position: relative` to be able to control element position via `style.left` and `style.top`, and use `MouseEvent.movementX` and `MouseEvent.movementY` to update position according to the cursor movements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<head>
  <title>Drag-n-drop</title>
  <style>
    .dragme {
      position: relative;   
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: grey;
    }
  </style>
</head>    
<body>

  <div class="dragme"></div>

  <script>
    const box = document.querySelector(".dragme");
    box.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", dragStop);

    function dragStart(event) {
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", dragging);
    }

    function dragging(event) {
      const style = window.getComputedStyle(box);
      box.style.left = `calc(${style.left} + ${event.movementX}px)`;
      box.style.top = `calc(${style.top} + ${event.movementY}px)`;
    }

    function dragStop(event) {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", dragging);
    }
  </script>

</body>    
</html>
```

The problem is, this approach works as intended in Firefox, but in Chrome and Edge, the dragged element moves faster than the cursor. After some investigation, I realized that the source of the problem is highDPI screen. Replacing `event.movementX` by `event.movementX / window.devicePixelRatio` etc. makes Chrome and Edge perform dragging flawlessly, but not Firefox.

The only cross-browser solution I came up with is to use `MouseEvent.screenX` and `MouseEvent.screenY` instead and I'm perfectly fine with it. However, I'm still curious is there any ways to be able to use `MouseEvent.movementX` and `MouseEvent.movementY` across different browsers?

Comment: I have a similar problem with a drag and drop functionality that relies on the movementX and Y values, it actually worked fine until a Chrome update (that happened around the beginning of this year), which made it three times sensitive on my laptop with a device pixel ratio of 3.